# DB25 recording outs include effects and equalization

Tags: audio-recording, mixing

I have question related with my mixer but really it is related with the DB25 connectors.

My Mackie Onyx 1620 has two different DB25 connectors with independent outputs by channel. Currently I have not bought the cable (30€+-) and previously I would like to know if the output or the signal for each channel is pure without equalization or effects or outputs recorded since this cable is including the effects and eq.

Thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the [user manual](https://supportloudtech.netx.net/loud-public/#asset/10603), the *recording outs* are just after the input gain control. So before low-cut, insert and EQ.

This means that the audio coming out of these outputs is just gain adapted by the gain control but is not affected by low-cut, insert and EQ.

As an example : if you record these outputs and switch on a low-cut on the channel, this low-cut will not be active for the recorded output.

Comment: Than the recoding would be with effects an eq, right?

Comment: @inane : no. I have added some details to my answer.

Comment: Ok thank you.. So it is a good configuration if you are working with software plugins and your production is in the computer but you are using hardware maybe it is not the correct way.. What do you think?

Comment: Do you know if the recording from the firewire card is the same behavior of the DB25 recoding outs? currently I do not have this card and maybe it could be a good idea for my purpose.